# Python; Line number not repeating in script after looking for ASCII character

Tags: python-3.x, logic, line-numbers

TL;DR - I need a line number count to repeat, but it's not.

I've looked to see if there's anything that can answer my specific question, and I've gotten a lot of help and nearly have this solved, but just have a question on what is returning for me.

I have a file with a list of peoples' names. It contains a column for Given Name, Surname, and through that I can obtain the full name. What I am trying to do is ascertain whether or not a non-ASCII character is in the name, what character that is, and what line number in the file that name may be found.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
with open('testFile.txt', 'r') as myFile:
    for l in lastName:
        if 0 <= ord(l) <= 127:
            pass
        else:
            for num, line in enumerate(myFile, start=1):
                if lastName in line:
                    print('Line number:', num)
            print('Unicode Character:', l, '\n')
    for f in firstName:
        if 0 <= ord(f) <= 127:
            pass
        else:
            for num, line in enumerate(myFile, start=1):
                if firstName in line:
                    print('Line number:', num)
            print('Unicode Character:', f, '\n')
```

The results work 'okay' but they're not complete. For example, if my file had three names:

- Hélen Duçére
- Mike Johnson
- Aïda Flannery

My results look like this:

```
Line Number: 1
Unicode Character: é

Unicode Character: ç

Unicode Character: é

Line Number: 3
Unicode Character: ï
```

Is there something obvious in my code to identify exactly why I'm not getting a repeat of the Line Number for that ç or the second é character? Is there a simpler way to write this?

Comment: What are the values of `lastName` and `firstName`? Are they parsed from your file? Where? And if so, why do you look at the file again?

Comment: @KyrSt The values would be "Duçére", "Johnson", and "Flannery" for lastName and "Hélen", "Mike", and "Aïda" for firstName. Yes, they are parsed over from the file. The file is something I receive from an outside source, whereby I won't know whether or not there are non-ASCII characters in there until I run the script, so I have to look at that script first. My next step would be to build a library for replacements. Example, if I have a name with a 'é' character, I would replace it with a standard 'e'. The database I need to ingest this data to can not accept these Unicode characters.

Comment: Then why the code for parsing those variables is not included? Or the code you posted the whole script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is a little more compact.

The `sub` method of regex arranges to substitute patterns that match its first parameter with the value of its second parameter, in the value of its third. The pattern `[a-zA-Z ]` looks for a single ascii character or a blank. Thus the `sub` will replace non-ascii characters or blanks with empty strings.

```
import re

with open ('will.txt') as will:
    for n, line in enumerate(will):
        remaining = re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z ]', '', line.rstrip())
        if remaining:
            print ('Line number:', n+1, 'non-ascii', remaining)
```

Edit: Making use of KyrSt's comment, the regex should contain some other characters, including, for instance, "'" and "-".

Edit 2: After exhaustive discussion with KyrSt, I've come to the conclusion that he's right, the regex should be `[\x00-\x7F]`

Comment: great and compact. My only "complain" is in your regex. I think removing all letters is not enough. Names may have other (ascii) characters too, like `-` or some other that I cannot think of right now but may be present.

Comment: A better approach would be the regex to match all ascii characters. That is `[\x00-\x7F]` if I'm not mistaken. Maybe edit your answer that way in fact.

Comment: That's correct, @KyrSt, I have to account for those other names (Jean-Claude, and any variation with accents on the characters). To answer your previous question, I wasn't posting the full script; that's on a separate computer not linked up; I can't pass that information back and forth easily, so I was handjamming that script back in. But I'm going to try these solutions; thank you!

Comment: @KyrSt: Your 2nd comment: I would venture to say that it depends on the precise intentions of Mr Dutcher. Should digits and all punctuation characters be excluded, or should they be investigated?

Comment: @WillDutcher I agree, but since in the original code all ascii characters are accepted, I suppose that would apply to the regex too, right? A minor detail either way

Comment: @KyrSt: As much as I hate to admit it :) , you're right again.

Comment: This one is repeating for every line it finds an offending 'hit' on a Unicode character. I'm going to look into these some more, as it may require additional realignments of my scripts to make everything 'fit' into place. Again, I think you all very much!

Comment: @WillDutcher: (a) You're very welcome. (b) Can you post the file you want to process, perhaps on pastebin?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, I'm sorry. When I'm at work, I have to kind of make up the data from scratch as I'm unable to do a simple copy/paste.

Comment: @WillDutcher: Can you give us the sample data that produced the untoward behaviour?

Comment: I have to leave now, as my wife works today so I have to pick up the kids, but I'll be sure to get back to this. I just noticed something else that may be an issue; the file we received is encoded in ANSI. I wonder if that's why when I used your script I was getting weirder results. For example, the ï character would return as normal when the .txt file was encoded ANSI, but return as an A and _ when encoded UTF-8.

Comment: I think I see what the problem is. `for num, line in enumerate(myFile, start=1):` yields the `num` variable correctly, for the enumerate, but the `line` results put in question marks for every character in the name; ex: if his name was Jim Smith, it would read ??? ?????, so because of that, I'm unable to get a line read from my `if lastName in line:` piece of code. Any ideas?

Comment: @WillDutcher: I didn't intend that my code would be mixed with yours. Perhaps you could provide your entire code, as it exists now, in your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wish I could, but I can't port it over for various security reasons; I had to hand-jam everything above, and there are 400+ lines of code that I'd have to port over, which I don't think I'd be able to charge for that, contractually. I'm sorry, and I know you guys are trying to help. I'll talk to the person that wrote the original code (who's got a ton more experience in Python than I) and see if he can piece together why I'm getting the errors I am.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a simpler way to approach this. Including the parsing of the names and providing you set an appropriate value for variable `delimiter` below, the code you want could be like this

```
line_number = 0
with open('testFile.txt', 'r') as myFile:

    line = myFile.readline().replace('\n','')

    while line != '':

        line_number += 1

        firstName, lastName = line.split(delimiter)

        for l in firstName:
            if ord(l) > 127 or ord(l) < 0:
                print('Line number:', line_number)
                print('Unicode Character:', l, '\n')

        for l in lastName:
            if ord(l) > 127 or ord(l) < 0:
                print('Line number:', line_number)
                print('Unicode Character:', l, '\n')


        line = myFile.readline().replace('\n','')
```

Comment: The one appears to be getting hung up once I start incrementing the line number. I may have to go through all my code to understand what's going on. I should have mentioned (which I'm sure is evident) that I'm a complete novice to this.